# Чёрная ложь. Значение выражения

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, словосочетания

Из анонса телепередачи:
*В то время, когда большинство людей помогали чем могли, другие распространяли в интернете **чёрную ложь*** (о событиях в Магнитогорске).

Словосочетание **чёрная/белая зависть** всем известно и большинству понятно.
А может ли ложь быть чёрной или белой? Каков в этом случае смысл выражения?

P.S. В словарных статьях я нашла только это:
[неправда](https://epithets.academic.ru/579/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0) — изменная (Суриков); лукавая (Некрасов); чёрная (Хомяков).

Answer (score 6):

По смыслу ложь может быть черной и белой, что определяется **ее целью:** это ложь во спасение или во вред.

Определений у лжи множество, но черная ложь ― это ложь ***злобная, злонамеренная, коварная***

А вот наше отношение к подобной лжи выражается словами ***грязная, отвратительная,  гнусная, подлая, циничная.***

Словарь сочетаемости: [https://kartaslov.ru/какой-бывает/ложь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C)

Comment: _По смыслу ложь может быть черной и белой..._ Это понятно. А говорить-то так грамотно? Я не встречалась ни с выражением черная, ни с выражением белая ложь. И в словарях этих словосочетаний нет.

Comment: Я думаю, что это авторский окказионализм (авторское сочетание), поэтому лучше его не употреблять.

Answer (score 2):

> А может ли ложь быть чёрной или белой?

Белой, пожалуй, нет. Потому что намного шире распространены выражения "святая ложь", "ложь во благо" и даже "сладкая ложь" (хотя последнее зачастую с негативным оттенком, но не всегда). Для сравнения, в английском языке распространены антонимичные идиомы "white lie / black lie". В переводах с английского встречается выражение "чёрная ложь". То же можно наблюдать и в некоторых других языках, поэтому, наверное, "белая ложь" иногда проникает в русский (в качестве кальки, я думаю).

Что касается эпитета "чёрный", можно вспомнить знакомое и понятное всем выражение "чёрная клевета". Я думаю, что "чёрная ложь" — это ложь, которая имеет целью нанести вред тем, кому она адресована. Это выражение мне кажется вполне естественным и понятным.

Comment: Да, похоже, что это на совести некоторых  переводчиков. В английском есть ещё (буквально) "белая" и "голубая" ложь, но "черную" в большинстве случаев можно перевести просто как "ложь" (это ложь намеренная и ничем не оправданная - без усложнённых смыслов). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie#Types

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы упомянули Магнитогорск,  где недавно произошедшие события связаны с гибелью людей, выражение "чёрная ложь" здесь употреблено по аналогии с "чёрным юмором"- человеку больно, он страдает,  а кому-то смешно.  Так и здесь: люди находятся в трауре, скорбят, страдают, а у кого-то хватает наглости лгать. Для того, чтобы подчеркнуть, насколько бессердечна подобная ложь, автор и "наградил" её эпитетом" чёрная ".

Comment: В русском ложь бывает "наглая" и "грязная" - видимо, у автора слов не хватило.